# Equality in Problem $2.12$, Rudin's RCA - Show that $h = \int_{\Omega} h\, d\mu$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, jensen-inequality

> Suppose $\mu(\Omega) = 1$, and $h: \Omega\to [0,\infty]$ is measurable. If $A = \int_\Omega h\, d\mu$, prove that $$\sqrt{1+A^2} \le \int_\Omega \sqrt{1+h^2}\, d\mu$$ and that equality holds iff $h = A$ a.e.

---

So I chose $\varphi(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}$ and used Jensen's inequality to get the result. It is also clear that equality holds if $h = A$ almost everywhere. However, **how does equality imply $h = A$ a.e.?**

I guess what I'm really asking is, when does equality hold in Jensen's inequality? From what I understand, equality implies that the inequality (3) below in Rudin, is an equality a.e. Hence, $$ \varphi(f(x)) - \varphi(t) = \beta (f(x) - t) \quad \text{a.e.}$$
Would this mean that $\varphi$ is an affine function? If yes, it'd be of the form $\varphi(x) = Bx + C$. That's weird though, since $\sqrt{1+x^2} = Bx + C$ is impossible unless $x = 0$, and $C = 1$. What am I missing? Could someone please clarify this in detail?

Thank you!

---

For reference:

> Jensen's inequality from Rudin:
> [image]
> Here's 3.1(2):
> [image]

Comment: That is exactly right, the equality in Jensen's inequality occurs at affine functions. The function that should be affine is $\varphi \circ f.$ In your particular case $\varphi$ is strictly convex, so if $f$ takes more than two values, the strict inequality would kick in. This solves your problem. Can you see why?

Comment: (1) Why $\varphi\circ f$ and not $\varphi$? Many people have said this but I'm struggling to deduce it. (2) *"..if $f$ takes more than two values, strict inequality would kick in."* - Why? I see how this solves the problem though. We have equality, so strict inequality is a contradiction. Hence $f$ (in our case $h$) is constant, and that gives $h = A$ a.e.

Comment: You obtain Jensen's inequality from (3), not from (2).

Comment: Correct. So if $\varphi \circ f$ is affine, we have $\varphi (f(x)) = Bx + C$ right? It'd help if you could answer the other parts too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right, it was not so obvious.

$u(s) = \varphi(s) - \varphi(t) - \beta(s - t).$ Then $u \geq 0.$ Consider $\mathrm{A} = \{f = t\}$ and $\mathrm{B} = \{f \neq t\}.$ When $\varphi$ is strictly convex (as in your case), then $u \circ f = 0$ on $\mathrm{A}$ and $u \circ f > 0$ on $\mathrm{B}.$ However, when $\int\limits_\Omega \varphi \circ f d\mu = \varphi \left( \int\limits_\Omega f d \mu \right),$ the integral of $u \circ f$ is zero, this implies
$$
0 = \int\limits_\Omega u \circ f d\mu = \int\limits_\mathrm{B} u \circ f d\mu
$$
and since the integrand in the last integral is positive while the integral is zero, we see that the set we are integrating against must be null relative to $\mu.$ Q.E.D.

Comment: This shows that the equality in Jensen's inequality happens (in the strictly convex case) if and only if $f$ is constant relative to $\mu.$ In particular, we see that the moments of random variables are strictly increasing (until the moment the become identically equal to infinity -pun intended-).

Comment: Why is $u \circ f > 0$ on $B$? My definition of strict convexity says that if $\varphi$ is strictly convex on $(a,b)$, then for all $0<t<1$ and $x,y \in (a,b)$, $\varphi(tx + (1-t)y) < t\varphi(x) + (1-t)\varphi(y)$. What $x,y$,and $t$ do you suggest I take? Is there an alternative definition of strict convexity?

Comment: If you follow the proof in Rudin, you have to replace the $\leq$ in 3.1(2) with a $<.$ Then (2) in the proof must replace $\geq$ with $>$ except at $s = t$ where we clearly have an equality. The rest goes through.

Comment: We need to be very careful. $\beta$ is the supremum, so even if there is strict inequality in 3.1(2), it is very much allowed and possible that (2) hold with equality. Showing that $s = t$ is the only case where equality holds is not trivial, in my opinion. Could you throw some light? Hope you understand my concern. Just saw the pun, nice one!

Comment: If $\varphi$ is strictly convex, then $\dfrac{\varphi(t) - \varphi(s)}{t - s} < \dfrac{\varphi(u) - \varphi(t)}{u - t} < \dfrac{\varphi(v) - \varphi(u)}{u - v}$ for any $a < s < t < u < v < b$ (this is known as __three chord lemma__). Then, $\beta \leq  \dfrac{\varphi(u) - \varphi(t)}{u - t} < \dfrac{\varphi(v) - \varphi(u)}{u - v}$ for all $s < t < u < v < b.$